# Prevent word from being added to the dictionary

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, swype, dictionary

I have a Samsung Galaxy S. My understanding is that pressing space after manually entering a word will add that word to the dictionary. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

That is not supported, but there are some workarounds:

- You could change language to something unused, before pressing space, and switching back afterwards.
- Or you may enter two spaces and place the cursor in between, and then type the word.

I really like Swype, but that's one of its drawbacks...